# On Windows 10, screensaver causes desktops to swap between monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup on windows 10. Whenever the screensaver kicks in and I unlock the laptop, I discover all programs that were on my left monitor are now on my right monitor, and vice versa.

Is there a way to quickly undo the change?

Answer (score 0):

Found on Reddit (djlewt):

Winkey+E to open file explorer, click view, options, "change folder and search options", select the view tab, uncheck "hide protected operating system files", confirm and close the options out, go to your desktop and delete any "desktop.ini" files, you most likely have 2 or more of them and that is your problem.

Make sure it fixes the issue by moving some icons around and rebooting, if fixed turn that option back off in explorer, you don't want to see those files.

If you have no desktop.ini file then your desktop folder probably has weird user permissions preventing that file from being created or you're out of disk space.

Comment: No, this does not address the problem scenario I posted